# Is There A Plugin to Create WP Multisite Installs programatically

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, admin, rest-api, api

So I created a wordpress multi-site and I want to be able to create multiple sites in the network programmatically. My subscription service has an API so I can create username and passwords on the fly when they sign up I just need to be able to create the site with some defaults when they sign up.

Also if there is a good Admin tool to manage these sites that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several really good plugins, like ["MultiSite Clone Duplicator"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-clone-duplicator/), that allow you to clone/duplicate and existing site.

I run a multisite installation with over 200 sites.  We started by creating a basic "template" site, which held all the basic/default settings we wanted for every new site.  Then, we just clone that each time we want a new site.

The newly created site can then have new administrators and editors created. Our team is already setup as super admins, and (thanks to cloning) local site admins for every site.

For more admin/management tools, you might refer to [this article](https://colorlib.com/wp/wordpress-multisite-plugins/). It has a list of plugins (some I've used, some not) to help you manage multisite networks easier.

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: That's awesome! Is there any way to do it programmatically so I don't have to manually click the buttons. I'd like to set up a subscription service.

Also do you suggest any user management plugins (or any other must-have plugins) to help keep everything organized?

Comment: There are many MANY plugins for such things.  Unfortunately, I have no experience with them, I could only perform a search of the plugin libraries, same as you could.  For example, I found ["Network Subsite User Registration"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/network-subsite-user-registration/) which will allow your new subscribers "Admin" access to register new users for their subsite only. That eliminates the need for all users to be registered on the main (root) WP site.  I'm sure creative searching will turn up others to help.

Comment: Back ...  As I clicked away, I found one you might want to check out. The title is ["Create your own Wordpress.com site"](https://wpultimo.com/).  It is a premium plugin that promises to do exactly what you want.  Again .. I have not affiliation, nor any experience with their product(s), but ... Thought you might find it useful.  Good luck!

Comment: You are amazing Mike. Thanks for taking the time to serve your fellow WP Devs! It's appreciated!